# How to use same column name and value name in Where condition(MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

```
SELECT * 
FROM price 
WHERE parts = parts;
```

If column name and value name are same it will return all data from table.

Comment: If it is the same name, try use `parts = "parts"` or `parts='parts'`.

Comment: Works well....@ Cenderze

Comment: Glad it worked, I added an answer with some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code,

```
Select * from `price` where `parts`='parts'
```

Here I'm using **`** key which is found before 1 on your keyboard.

And for value use single quote

Comment: dbo is MSSQL not MySQL

Answer (score 0):

I saw that my comment worked, so I'll add that as an answer.

If you are to make a `Where` statement on an integer, you can do as you did, i.e. `Where parts = 1` and it would work.

However you cannot do this with strings, for strings you must include the `''`, so:

```
Select * from DataBaseName.price WHERE price = 'parts'
```

I presume that you are new to SQL? It is best practice to, instead of using `Select *` use `Select [List of column names]`, for instance `Select Price, Store` or whatever you have. This will avoid you importing many more columns than perhaps needed, especially if you add more columns to the table at a later stage which is irrelevant for this instance.

Perhaps you already knew this, but I figure it is worth to mention...

Comment: dbo is MSSQL not MySQL

Comment: @RaymondNijland   Thanks, I'll adjust. Haven't used MySQL really, only SQL Server.